# Same screenshot obtained with different capture methods giving different OCR results

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract, image-preprocessing

I am taking screenshots on Android with two different methods:

1. By running `/system/bin/screencap -p $path`.
2. With the `MediaProjection` API.

Even though it's the exact same screen, when performing OCR (with the use of `Tesseract`) I get different results.

With `/system/bin/screencap` I get the expected results.
With the `MediaProjection` API is unable to recognise all text correctly, hence I need to preprocess the image.

Why is that? Maybe it depends on different configurations of the Bitmap file I pass as argument to `Tesseract`?
Meaning the bitmap decoded from the system command has a different configuration than the bitmap created from the mediaprojection API?

This is how I am creating the bitmap from the `MediaProjection` API:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MediaProjection/andshooter/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/andshooter/ImageTransmogrifier.java

Comment: present the data, compare it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz any suggestion on which data I would need to print? I mean the relevant ones.

Comment: dump both pictures, compare all values.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz any idea how to achieve that programatically? The compare part, I mean.

Comment: take per-pixel absolute difference, look at result